# check if control exists on the left side of another control

Tags: vb6

How can i find if a control exists on the left side of another control.
For example we usually place labels on the left to text box. in my from I have more than 50
controls and i want to enlarge them. Enlarging one by one is time consuming. How can i find a control and its width, placed left to another. Can anyone suggest an way to achieve this in code. I am using vb6. This is my code and this is not working

```
For Each crl In Me.Controls
    'crl.Width = crl.Width + 750
    If crl.Left < 150 Then
        crl.Left = crl.Left + 2000
    Else
        crl.Left = (crl.Width / 2) + crl.Left + 1000
    End If
    crl.Top = crl.Top + 500
    'crl.Height = crl.Height + 100
    'crl.Width = crl.Width + 750
Next
```

Comment: By "time consuming" do you mean enlarging them in the IDE designer? ctrl+click them all then you only need to set *width* once.

Comment: @AlexK. setting the width only makes the controls to overlap and cannot set properties of different controls at once

Comment: after you changed the width (like Alex suggested), you can use the align function from the menu to put them all in place, just position the top left control, align the controls to the right of it, and then for each column as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some logical structure in the layout of your controls?

If that is the case then you can use the Form_Resize() event to position (and resize) the controls

for example a form with 10 labels and 10 textboxes in a layout of 5 x 2 rows x columns

```
'1 form with:
'1 textbox : name=Text1   Index=0
'1 label   : name=Label1  Index=0
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  'load extra labels and textboxes
  For intIndex = 1 To 9
    Load Label1(intIndex)
    Label1(intIndex).Caption = "Label" & CStr(intIndex + 1)
    Label1(intIndex).Visible = True
    Load Text1(intIndex)
    Text1(intIndex).Text = "Text" & CStr(intIndex + 1)
    Text1(intIndex).Visible = True
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim intRow As Integer, intCol As Integer
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  'calculate width and height of each control
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth / 4
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight / 5
  'loop through all controls and position and resize them
  For intIndex = 0 To 9
    intCol = intIndex \ 5
    intRow = intIndex Mod 5
    Label1(intIndex).Move 2 * intCol * sngWidth, intRow * sngHeight, sngWidth, sngHeight
    Text1(intIndex).Move (2 * intCol + 1) * sngWidth, intRow * sngHeight, sngWidth, sngHeight
  Next intIndex
End Sub
```